# Downloading part of an EJS page as a PDF file

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, ejs

I have little developing experience and I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction with my little project.

Basically, I have this first page where the user fills a form via radio buttons. These choices all represent pieces of texts in the database. When the form is submitted, an EJS page is rendered where these texts are merged. I've managed to make it work this far using Node, Express and MongoDB.

As the next step I'm trying to give the user the option to download the generated text as a nice looking PDF file. What would you recommend me to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like [node-html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) which takes a picture from your generated html page from EJS and print it using an headless browser.

Note : Since PhamtomJS is deprectated, node-html-pdf's too.